# Threaded/Unthreaded option in Thunderbird not working as expected

Tags: email, thunderbird

Thunderbird has had the concept of threads for the longest time, but I have always turned them off, and the feature has not bothered me until recently.

Whenever several messages+replies show up together in the same folder, the "View -> Sort By -> Threaded/Unthreaded" option seems to always revert back to "Threaded".
I have specifically selected "Unthreaded" as my preference. This has been set on all folders (although the only folder I have noticed the issue with is the Inbox).

Restarting TB, or restarting the computer does not seem to change anything, and everything seems OK. Nevertheless, every few days, there will be a thread of new messages that seems to trigger something, and "View -> Sort By" will immediately switch back to "Threaded". And it is super annoying. Is there anything that can be done?

Version is Thunderbird 115.6.0 (64-bit), Debian Linux

[image]